# how to update canavas layout after rotation in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, canvas

I have a main page with 2 canvas like this:

```
<Canvas Name="main_canvas_color" Width="480" Height="800" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
  <Canvas Name="main_canvas_image" Width="480" Height="800" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
   </Canvas>
 </Canvas>
```

the first one is filled by color the other one is filled by image. In PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged event a swap width and height for both canvas. If i rotate a screen, it works fine, everything positioned correctly. If I add a Border element as a children to main_canvas_image and then rotate screen, main_canvas_image is not updated in a right way, it is shifted  toward top right corner. If I open any another page and then go back after that, main_canvas_image is updated properly. So it seems that i have to force layout update, but i don't know how to do that. I tried UpdateLayout(); inside PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged event, but it does not work. How can I update canvas layout in a right way?

Answer (score 1):

Why bother ? The phone automatically adjust the size when you change the orientation. No reason to write code for it yourself.